# Using/importing azure-storage in my Angular2 environment with typescript

Tags: angular, azure, typescript, blob, azure-storage

I'm trying to set up my Angular2 environment so that i can create containers and upload files to my azure blob storage account.

I found this great guide: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-nodejs-how-to-use-blob-storage

however this doesn't help me with angular2/typescript.

After doing "npm install azure-storage --save" what are the correct steps for including the BlobService class in my app.module file? It seems like the BlobService class inside of azure-storage/typings/azure-storage/azure-storage.d.ts has many of the same functions that I would need to follow the above tutorial that I mentioned above, 
but "import {BlobSerice} from 'azure-storage';" and including BlobService in my imports doesn't seem to work.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NPM package you are using is Azure Storage SDK for Node.js while the Angular2 is front end framework. Technically they are different, Angular2 is on client side, but Node.js is on server side.

So, you'll need to set up Node.js back-end environment to create containers and upload files to your Azure Storage account.